# How to build a target added with CMAKEs `add_custom_target()`?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have a CMake file which I'm opening in vs2017 with `open folder` menu. In that CMake I added a custom target with `add_custom_target()` command but I'm not able to find an action to build it. All menus and pop-ups have only my main target added with `add_executable()`. But if I add `ALL` option to `add_custom_target()` it builds.

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio 2017 "Open Folder" feature? And with menu you are referring to "CMake/Build Only/<Target Name>"?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Visual Studio 2017 "Open Folder" feature on a CMake based project, there is at the moment no possibility to just build one of CMake project's custom target.

But this is known issue, see [Visual Studio: Developer Community: cmake custom targets not supported](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/127005/cmake-custom-targets-not-supported.html)

And the good news is, that a fix is coming soon (Version > 15.5.6):

> The fix for this is now in our latest Visual Studio Preview release. If you'd like to try out the fix, you can access the preview build here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview

Answer (score 1):

You can switch from folder view to CMake targets vies in the solution explorer, by clicking on the button "switching between solutions and available views. In the CMake targets list you can see all targets, also the ones created with `add_custom_target`.